# Success isn't calling after succesfull $.ajax request

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write some javascript inside :javascript closure in haml template. It should show/hide divs with controls according a status which it gets over ajax call. I can't get that code running right way. I don't have a clue why. Ajax handlers success and complete aren't called. Firebug shows successful ajax request and no errors in the console. I think "self" in Thin.ajax may be broken some way.

```
function Thin() {
  this.ajax = function() {
    $.ajax({ url: "#{check_if_running_user_case_path(@user_case)}", success: this.on_success, error: this.on_error, dataType: "json", complete: this.poll, timeout: 30000 });
  }

  this.poll = function() {
    alert("poll");
    setTimeout(this.ajax, 2000);
  };

  this.manage_divs = function(st) {
    if (st != this.running) {
      if (st == "running") {
        this.hide_div_arr_show_div([this.start_div, this.starting_div, this.stopping_div], this.stop_div);
      } else if (st == "starting"){
        this.hide_div_arr_show_div([this.start_div, this.stop_div, this.stopping_div], this.starting_div);
      } else if (st == "stopping"){
        this.hide_div_arr_show_div([this.start_div, this.stop_div, this.starting_div], this.stopping_div);
      } else {
        this.hide_div_arr_show_div([this.stopping_div, this.stop_div, this.starting_div], this.start_div);
      }
      this.running = st;
    }
  };

  this.setup  = function(start_div, starting_div, stop_div, stopping_div) {
    this.start_div    = start_div;
    this.starting_div = starting_div;
    this.stop_div     = stop_div;
    this.stopping_div = stopping_div;
    // set as stopped
    this.running = "12345";
    this.poll();
  };

  this.on_error   = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(["Thin polling error", textStatus]);
  };

  this.on_success = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert("success!");
    var st = data.user_case;
    this.manage_divs(st);
  };

  this.hide_div_arr_show_div  = function(div_arr, div){
    for(var i = 0; i < div_arr.length; i++)
        div_arr[i].hide();
    div.show();
  };
};

var thin = new Thin();
thin.setup($("#user_case_stopped"), $("#user_case_starting"), $("#user_case_running"), $("#user_case_stopping"));
thin.manage_divs("#{@running}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside jQuery's Ajax method `this` will refer to the global scope.  Trying reference your parent object explicitly to make sure you are using the correct scope (your object):

```
function Thin() {
    var that = this;

    that.ajax = function() {
                  $.ajax({ url: "#{check_if_running_user_case_path(@user_case)}",
                        success: that.on_success, 
                        error: that.on_error, 
                        dataType: "json", 
                        complete: that.poll, 
                        timeout: 30000 });
                }

    ...
```

Edit: Just for reference, [this is a nice article](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this) on scoping `this` in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that error in firefox, so I just inlined the success method.

instead of
 success: this.success

I used

```
success:function(){},
```

Comment: Yep I alsouse Fierfox. 

I can't use inline function instead of on_success, because it calls this.manage_divs, which in turn calls this.hide_div_arr_show_div, which couldn't be referenced from inline function.

Comment: Ok, As I see now, the curly braces open a new scope, do they?
    
    $.ajax({ url: some_path, success: this.on_success, error: this.on_error, dataType: "json", complete: this.poll, timeout: 30000 });